# Table of Contents missing from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, table-of-contents

I am new to ArcGIS Desktop 10.  I am using a students version on my home laptop.  I have lost my table of contents completely from the left side of my screen.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 8):

Just Windows -> Table Of Contents.

Comment: Now that was easy wasn't it? :)

Comment: BTW, if that doesn't fix it, you can try removing/renaming your [normal.mxt](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00v000000014000000) file.

Answer (score 2):

Window - -> Table of Contents then double click its title bar. The table of contents window will be docked with the viewer window.